# How to pass IEnumerable model to _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to pass a model to _Layout page for dynamic content editing.

Here is my _Layout

```
@model IEnumerable<Test.Models.Article>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
...
```

Later in _Layout I need to use this:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Single().Content) - this works fine
<a asp-controller="Articles" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="1">Edit</a> - error after clicking the edit button
```

This concept is working fine on all pages like Index, About etc. but not on _Layout.cshtml.

I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Test.Models.Article', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Test.Models.Article]'.

What shoud I do?

Edit:
Here is my HomeController:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Article.ToListAsync());
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> About()
    {
        return View(await _context.Article.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

Here is my ArticleController:

```
    public class ArticlesController : Controller
{
    public ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ArticlesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Articles
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Article.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: Articles/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var article = await _context.Article.FindAsync(id);
        if (article == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(article);
    }

    // POST: Articles/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Content")] Article article)
    {
        if (id != article.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(article);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ArticleExists(article.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(article);
    }
```

The whole _Layout:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test.Models.Article>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - PermanentTetovani</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/default.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />

    <!-- HEADER : begin -->
    <header id="header" class="m-animated">
        <div class="header-bg">
            <div class="header-inner">

                <!-- HEADER BRANDING : begin -->
                <div class="header-branding">
                    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="Permanentní tetování" data-hires="../images/logo.2x.png" width="291"></a>
                </div>
                <!-- HEADER BRANDING : end -->
                <!-- HEADER NAVIGATION : begin -->
                <div class="header-navigation">

                    <!-- HEADER MENU : begin -->
                    <nav class="header-menu">
                        <button class="header-menu-toggle" type="button"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>MENU</button>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="@((ViewBag.PageName == "Index") ? "m-active" : "")">
                                <span><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Úvodní stránka</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="@((ViewBag.PageName == "About") ? "m-active" : "")">
                                <span><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">O nás</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="@((ViewBag.PageName == "Gallery") ? "m-active" : "")">
                                <span><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Gallery">Galerie</a></span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="@((ViewBag.PageName == "Contact") ? "m-active" : "")">
                                <span><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Kontakt</a></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- HEADER MENU : end -->
                </div>
                <!-- HEADER NAVIGATION : end -->
                <!-- HEADER PANEL : begin -->
                <div class="header-panel">

                    <button class="header-panel-toggle" type="button"><i class="fa"></i></button>

                    <!-- HEADER RESERVATION : begin -->
                    <div class="header-reservation">
                        <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact" class="c-button">Domluvit si schůzku</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- HEADER RESERVATION : end -->
                    <!-- HEADER CONTACT : begin -->
                    <div class="header-contact">
                        <ul>

                            <!-- PHONE : begin -->
                            <li>
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                    <i class="ico fa fa-phone"></i>
                                    <strong>721 805 741</strong>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- PHONE : end -->
                            <!-- EMAIL : begin -->
                            <li>
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                    <i class="ico fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                                    777michaelahavlova<br>
                                    @@seznam.cz
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- EMAIL : end -->
                            <!-- ADDRESS : begin -->
                            <li>
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                    <i class="ico fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                    <strong>PERMANENT TETOVÁNÍ</strong><br>
                                    Jihočeská univerzita, Vančurova 2904<br>
                                    Tábor 390 01
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- ADDRESS : end -->
                            <!-- HOURS : begin -->
                            <li>
                                <div class="item-inner">
                                    <i class="ico fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                    <dl>
                                        <dt>Po. - Pá.:</dt>
                                        <dd>Dle dohody</dd>
                                        <dt>So.:</dt>
                                        <dd>Dle dohody</dd>
                                        <dt>Ne.:</dt>
                                        <dd>Zavřeno</dd>
                                    </dl>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- HOURS : end -->

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- HEADER CONTACT : end -->
                </div>
                <!-- HEADER PANEL : end -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- HEADER : end -->
    <!-- WRAPPER : begin -->
    <div id="wrapper">

        @RenderBody()

        <!-- BOTTOM PANEL : begin -->
        <div id="bottom-panel">
            <div class="bottom-panel-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <!-- BOTTOM TEXT : begin -->
                            <div class="bottom-text various-content">
                                <h3>O našem studiu</h3>
                                <!--
                                <p><strong>Permanentní make-up</strong> provádím v Táboře v Jihočeské univerzitě, kde nabízím tyto služby: <strong>permanentní tetování obočí, rtů a očních linek</strong>.</p>
                                <p>Je potřeba se nejprve předem objednat!</p>
                                -->

                                @Html.Raw(Model.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Single().Content)
                                <a asp-controller="Articles" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="1">Edit</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- BOTTOM TEXT : end -->

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <!-- BOTTOM SUBSCRIBE : begin -->
                            <div class="bottom-subscribe various-content">

                                <h3>Kontakt</h3>
                                <p>Využijte prosím náš kontaktní formulář.</p>
                                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact" class="c-button">Kontaktujte nás</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- BOTTOM SUBSCRIBE : end -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- BOTTOM PANEL : end -->
        <!-- FOOTER : begin -->
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="container">

                <!-- FOOTER BOTTOM : begin -->
                <div class="footer-bottom">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">

                            <!-- FOOTER MENU : begin -->
                            <nav class="footer-menu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Úvodní stránka</a></li>
                                    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">O nás</a></li>
                                    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Gallery">Galerie</a></li>
                                    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Register">Administrace</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                            <!-- FOOTER MENU : end -->

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">

                            <!-- FOOTER TEXT : begin -->
                            <div class="footer-text">
                                <p>
                                    ©
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        var today = new Date()
                                        var year = today.getFullYear()
                                        document.write(year)
                                    </script>
                                    PermanentTetovani.cz | Vytvořil <a href="http://www.prognet.cz/">ProgNet.cz</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- FOOTER TEXT : end -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- FOOTER BOTTOM : end -->

            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- FOOTER : end -->

    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
        </script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your method in controller. You may have passed a single article not an IEnumerable of Articles

Comment: Actually I need all articles as I have dynamic web content editing. That means that each paragraph is an article. So one page like Index has for example 5 articles. According to IDs I display the articles on the page.

My Home Controller:
   public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Article.ToListAsync());
        }

Comment: @LukášHavel Can you edit your question and include `HomeController`, `ArticlesController` and also the rest of the layout?

Comment: what is the model provided from the edit action of the Articles controller? I believe the issue is from the edit action to the layout. Could you provide the edit action method ?

Comment: @Florin-Constantin Ciubotariu

Please see the edits above

Comment: @LukášHavel Can you also inspect the HTML generated by that view and paste it here?

Comment: @Florin-Constantin Ciubotariu what do you mean by "inspect the HTML generated by that view" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lukáš, I found the reason of your exception and will try my best to describe it.
From the process below, when reload `edit view`, it will load `_layout.cshtml` then render `Edit.cshtml`.You defined the @model IEnumerable<Test.Models.Article>
but return view(Ariticle).

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

> What's the simplest solution?

open `Views/Articles/Edit.cshtml` add codes below

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

[image]

Screenshots of test:

[image]

> WARNING

I have to remind you even though `Edit` works but others still have same problems.
`_Layout.cshtml` was added to each `Views` from `_ViewStart.cshtml`.

The layout specified can use a full path (for example, /Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml or /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml) or a partial name (example: _Layout). When a partial name is provided, the Razor view engine searches for the layout file using its standard discovery process. The folder where the handler method (or controller) exists is searched first, followed by the Shared folder. This discovery process is identical to the process used to discover partial views.

The details about [Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I already get it. But another problems accured...
If I click the Edit button and Edit View is shown, I can not see my WYSIWYG editor. It is in @section Scripts. Also I can not see the _Layout while Edit View is displayed. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Setting @{
    Layout = null;
} , the _Layout will not load in your Edit View, it will resolve @model conflict(your question) but you can't see _Layout and also Scripts.

Comment: The not recommended but simple solution is copying _Layout codes you need  to your Edit View. The recommended but time-consuming solution is recode _Layout mentioned in my first answer.

Comment: thank you, your solution solved my problem. It has only one disadvantage: I can't see my layout in Edit view.

In my case, I finally did a workaround: I am using [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1) instead. That was what I needed.